# XML Comments for "Description" section of Properties in service Message Contract documentation using Sandcastle

Tags: c#, web-services, documentation, documentation-generation, sandcastle

I'm attempting to generate documentation for a web service in C# using Sandcastle.

What I'd like to accomplish is adding a description to the properties of a request MessageContract:[image: Description Section]

Here's a snippit the code I have right now:

```
namespace RWS.MessageContracts
{
/// <summary>
/// Service Contract Class - GetCoverageDataDisclosuresRisksRequest
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>Request for the GetCoverageDataDisclosuresRisks method.</remarks>
[WCF::MessageContract(WrapperName = "GetCoverageDataDisclosuresRisksRequest", WrapperNamespace = "http://researchwebservice.model/research")] 
public partial class GetCoverageDataDisclosuresRisksRequest
{
    private RWS.DataContracts.UniqueIDCollection audienceTypeIdentifier;
    private RWS.DataContracts.ExchangeTicker exchangeTickers;
    private RWS.DataContracts.IntegerCollection organizations;
    private RWS.DataContracts.IntegerCollection companies;

    /// <remarks>Unique Identifier of an AudienceType <seealso cref="RWS.DataContracts.UniqueIDCollection"/></remarks>
    [WCF::MessageBodyMember(Namespace = "http://researchwebservice.model/research", Name = "AudienceTypeIdentifier")]
    public RWS.DataContracts.UniqueIDCollection AudienceTypeIdentifier
    {
        get { return audienceTypeIdentifier; }
        set { audienceTypeIdentifier = value; }
    }
```

How should I comment this code to get the remarks I have now ("Unique Identifier of an AudienceType") to show up in this section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The descriptions are based on the `<summary>` tags. I think you should just change the `<remarks>` tags to `<summary>`. The remarks section is only shown on the property's page and should contain additional, detailed information of the property.